# Where is the Translation Information about an item stored?

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions, translation-manager

I am looking to create a report for my business partners on the content in our installation of Tridion. They want to know the following:

- What content has not been translated
- what content has been translated
- Does a new version need to be translated
- What is currently out for translation

The status of jobs is fairly easy. However, the translation status of items is not. We are currently on Tridion 2011 SP1. The translation information in question is not stored in the TM Database (that I can tell). My fear is that it is in application cache files on the local file system. I have written some ajax to call the TM load service:

```
/WebUI/Models/TM2010/Services/TranslationInfoManager.svc/Load
```

but that is very tedious and does not support JSONp...so it must be ran from the server. With no TM hookup in the CoreService, is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is stored in app data, only cached data is ever stored on the filesystem. It is not in a public API format, which means it can change between tridion versions (and in theory even with a hot fix), and you will not find any documentation on it. But if you can live with these limitations it should be possible to extract the data.

Comment: I can live with that for now. Do you know where this app data is located for translation manager?

Comment: It's stored on the target item. I can't remember the app data id, but it starts with tm:, and I do not think tm stores any other appdata on target items so it should be possible to find. Appdata is binary, but if you throw the binary data into an XML reader as a byte stream you should get lucky.

Comment: The AppData inspector PowerTool should provide you with enough sample code to get to it: http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/AppDataInspector

Comment: Thank you guys. I already have some code to look into AppData...did not even think to start there.